# Replace a value in a vector if doesn't equal to two conditions (in R)

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector v. I would like to replace everything that doesn't equal S or D. It can be replaced by x.

```
v <- c("S","D","hxbasxhas","S","cbsdc")
```

result

```
r <- c("S","D","x","S","x")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can negate `%in%` :

```
v <- c("S","D","hxbasxhas","S","cbsdc")
v[!v %in% c('S', 'D')] <- 'x'
v
#[1] "S" "D" "x" "S" "x"
```

Or use `forcats::fct_other` :

```
forcats::fct_other(v, c('S', 'D'), other_level = 'x')
```

Answer (score 2):

A `stringr` approach is possible with a [negative look-around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/7153771).

Using `str_replace`:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(v, "^((?!S|D).)*$", "x")
```

Result:

```
[1] "S" "D" "x" "S" "x"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `which` statement is what you are looking for:

```
v[which(v!="S" & v!="D")]<-"x"
```